# Create distortion from basic linear (and non-linear if neccessary) DSP elements

Tags: linear-systems, non-linear, distortion

I'm studying mechatronics and I'm intrested in DSP basics. My lecturer said that there are four basic linear DSP elements:

1. Adder (and other mathematical operations)
2. Amplification (shown on diagrams as triangle)
3. Delay ($z^{-1}$)
4. Junction

I know from electronics that I can create distortion using for example op-amps and clipping circuits - and I can do it practically. But is there a way to create distortion using four DSP elements theoretically?
I know distortion is non-linear - so if not this four elements, what kind of elements existing in theoretically DSP should i use?

Comment: Can you control the gain of the amplification by another signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using those four basic elements will allow you to implement *linear* systems, which can change the magnitude and phase of the input signal, but which will not add the harmonics that are expected from a distortion effect. In order to create distortion in that sense (i.e., non-linear distortion) you will need some non-linear element. The most basic implementation would use a (soft) clipping function, possibly followed by some linear filter to shape the spectrum.

A very accessible reference is the [DAFX (Digital Audio Effects) book](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/dafx_book.pdf) edited by Udo Zölzer. It has a chapter on non-linear processing, including distortion and overdrive. Note that I found an error in one of the equations for producing distortion (Eq. (5.9)). You can find the corrected formula in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/28962/4298) to a related question.