# What kind of distortion effect is this?

Tags: audio, sound, distortion

Here is the image of a plugin distortion I have applied to a sine wave.
The sound characteristic is heavily distorted and digital but still good sounding bass wave.

Any ideas what kind of distortion this is and where to look for implementation? I currently implemented a wave shape distortion it squares the wave and doesn't sound nearly as good.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/38163/4298) and its answer.

Comment: Even more related: [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/87879/4298).

Answer (score 3):

If a sine wave was going in, because of the asymmetric waveshape coming out, it can't be a straight memoryless waveshaper.  The half wave coming out looks the impulse response of an overdamped or critically damped 2nd-order all-pole IIR filter.

So I think the sinewave is going in and

1. first getting clipped symmetrically, same for positive and negative (so polarity is not important).  This will generate ***only*** odd-numbered harmonics.  So it can be a [soft clipper as described here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/monotonic-symmetrical-soft-clipping-polynomial) but has to be reasonably high order and have a lotta input gain to make it look like hard clipping.
2. Then that clipped signal is getting a differentiator to turn the up and down edge into up and down impulses.
3. Then the up and down impulses are going into some second-order all-pole filter that is either overdamped or critically damped.

overdamped:
$$ h(t) = \big(e^{-\alpha_1 t} - e^{-\alpha_2 t}\big) \, u(t) $$

where $0 < \alpha_1 < \alpha_2$  or

critically damped:
$$ h(t) = t \, e^{-\alpha t} \, u(t) $$